# Confused on what the question is asking... Integration and Riemann sums

Tags: integration, riemann-sum

[image: Math Question]

So I know how to integrate, and I understand Riemann sums via Right hand, left, etc  but this question I am trying to answer has me baffled. I think its because its trying to be generic in the f(mx) and g(x) instead of actual values and that is tripping me up.

Am I suppose to be just showing how the equation is setup and you would replace the values? essentially I am stuck getting started on this problem as it doesn't feel intuitive to me.

I have added all the highlighted parts of the question to help in deciphering this.

[image: 5.5.1 Definition]
[image: 5.5.2 Theorem]
[image: 5.9.1 Theorem]

Comment: So, you'll have that $g$ is just like $f$ except that its as though $g$ has been *shrunk (horizontally) by a factor of $m$*.  If you prefer a specific example, suppose $f(x)=x$, then you have $g(x)=f(mx)=mx$, so on the interval $[0,1]$, $g$ forms a straight line from $(0,0)$ to $(1,m)$.  This is in comparison to $f$ on the interval $[0,m]$ which forms a straight line from $(0,0)$ to $(m,m)$.  Do you know any theorems about the area of a triangle given its base and its height?  Can you generalize this to different shapes and thus to arbitrary $f$?  Can you formalize this for reimann sums?

Comment: I think i can use anything to determine whether it is less than, equal, or greater between the two functions.  Sounds to me based on what you said is that the relation is smaller by the multiplication of m to the sum, b) would then be some kind of real equation example. and C seems to be including u substitution? and seeing if that equality is related...